# FluentValidation: Get CustomState on client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fluentvalidation

I want to integrate bootstraps `.alert alert-warning` classes with `FluentValidation` to show/hide warning messages. I thought I could put a custom state on the rule and send it to the client side to show and hide the alert message, but I cannot figure it out. here is what I have so far:

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<FooVm>
  {
    public FooValidator ()
    {
      RuleFor(model => model.Temperature)
        .NotNull()
        .LessThanOrEqualTo(model => model.MaxTemp)
          .WithState(model => ValidationType.Warning)
          .WithMessage("Warning, temp should be less than or equal to {ComparisonValue}")
        .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(model => model.MinTemp)
          .WithState(model => ValidationType.Warning)
          .WithMessage("Warning, temp should be greater than or equal to {ComparisonValue}");
    }
  }
```

and here is my LessThanOrEqualTo validator to get client rules. Please note I have a TODO at the end to set the state argument for the client

```
  public class LessThanOrEqualPropertyValidator : FluentValidationPropertyValidator
  {
    public LessThanOrEqualPropertyValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext, PropertyRule rule, IPropertyValidator validator)
      : base(metadata, controllerContext, rule, validator)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
      if (!ShouldGenerateClientSideRules()) yield break;

      var validator = (LessThanOrEqualValidator)Validator;
      object val;
      string variableInMsg;

      var propertyToCompare = validator.MemberToCompare as PropertyInfo;

      // get the value from the property instead of using the property
      if (propertyToCompare != null)
      {
        val = this.Metadata.Container.GetType().GetProperty(propertyToCompare.Name).GetValue(this.Metadata.Container, null);
        variableInMsg = "ComparisonValue";
      }
      else
      {
        val = validator.ValueToCompare;
        variableInMsg = "ValueToCompare";
      }

      var errorMessage = new MessageFormatter()
          .AppendPropertyName(Rule.GetDisplayName())
          .AppendArgument(variableInMsg, val)
          .BuildMessage(validator.ErrorMessageSource.GetString());

      var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
      rule.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
      rule.ValidationType = "lessthanorequal";
      rule.ValidationParameters["valuetocompare"] = val;
      rule.ValidationParameters["state"] = // TODO: how can i send state across, i know you can view it when validating the obj
      yield return rule;
    }
  }
```

and here is my client code where i want to be able to pick up state in the params object. Warnings will always return true;

```
$.validator.addMethod("lessthanorequal", function (value, element, params) {
    var isValid = this.optional(element) || parseFloat(value) <= parseFloat(params.valuetocompare)

    // TODO: how to get state
    //if(params.state === "Warning") {
    //    if (isValid) {
    //        $(".alert-warning").hide();
    //    }
    //    else {
    //        $(".alert-warning").show();
    //    }
    //    return true;
    //}

    return isValid
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("lessthanorequal", ["valuetocompare"], function (options) {
    options.rules['lessthanorequal'] = options.params;
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages['lessthanorequal'] = options.message;
    }
});
```

Comment: are you able to see all params are bounded with your UI element on client side?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Actually in client side unobtrusive binds the client side params on your Form element via data attributes. Are you able to see them? e.g.

<input type="text" value="" name="FieldName" id="FieldName" data-val-required="*required" data-val="true">

Comment: okay I see what you are saying. Under the `data-val-lessthanorequal-state` i see `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.Func\`3[System.Object,System.Object,System.Object]]`

Comment: So now you got the issue, this is why your validations are not working.

Answer (score 0):

kudos goes to @KundanSinghChouhan for pointing out something i should have seen. The state object was in the `data-val` attribute, but not as a value I could use directly on the client. below is what i did to get this to work in my `LessThanOrEqualPropertyValidator`

```
rule.ValidationParameters["state"] = this.CustomStateProvider.Invoke(null);
```

I do not know the ramifications it will have when the `ValidationError` list is posted back to the server because that class stores that `State` value, but I will review that if i ever need to use that class.